# I'm Trying to get property of non-object in my CI system.

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm Trying to get property of non-object in my CI system.

Everything is working fine while navigating my records from user 1 to user 11 but when I navigated to the last user which is user 12 I'm getting this error notice..

This is my Controller:

```
public function index()
    {

        $data['title']= 'Customer Card';
        $data['records'] = $this->customer_model->getAll();
        $data['taxcodes'] = $this->customer_model->getAllTaxCodes();
        $data['types'] = $this->customer_model->getAllCustomerTypes();
        $data['groups'] = $this->customer_model->getAllCustomerGroups();
        $data['groupcodes'] = $this->customer_model->getAllCustomerGroups();

        $shown_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        if(!is_numeric($shown_id)){
            $shown_id = 0;
        } 
        if($shown_id == ""){
            $shown_id = 1;
        }
        $data['info'] = $this->customer_model->fetch_customers(1, $shown_id);
        $data['last_id'] = $this->customer_model->last_customer();

        $this->load->view('include/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('include/navbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('customer_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('include/sidebar', $data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer', $data);

    }
```

View:

```
    <?php

            $customer_id = $info->customercode_id;
            $customer_code = $info->customercode;
            $customer_name = $info->customername;
            $customer_type = $info->typedescription;
            $customer_group = $info->customergroup;
            $customer_address = $info->customeraddress;
            $customer_addressalt = $info->customeraddressalt;
            $customer_grp_desc = $info->groupdescription;
            $customer_phone1 = $info->phone1;
            $customer_phone2 = $info->phone2;
            $customer_fax = $info->fax;
            $customer_email = $info->email;
            $customer_website = $info->website;
            $tax_code = $info->taxcode;

        ?>
```

Model:

```
function getAllCustomerGroups()
        {

            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT customergroup, description FROM customergrouplist');
            return $query->result();

        }

        function getAllTransactionTypes()
        {

            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT description FROM transactioncodelist');
            return $query->result();

        }

        function getAllCustomerTypes()
        {

            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT customertypecode, customertypedescription FROM customertype');
            return $query->result();

        }

        function getAllTaxCodes()
        {

            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT tax_id, taxcode FROM tax');
            return $query->result();

        }

        function getAll() {
            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT customercode, customername, 
            customergroup, customertype, customeraddress, 
            website FROM customercard LIMIT 1');
            return $query->result();
        }

        function getLastID() {
            //$query = $this->db->query('SELECT max(customercode_id) FROM customercard');
            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT customercode_id FROM customercard ORDER BY customercode_id DESC LIMIT 1');
            return $query->row()->customercode_id;
        }

        public function fetch_customers($limit, $start) {
            $this->db->select('
            customercard.customercode_id, 
            customercard.customercode, 
            customercard.customername, 
            customercard.customergroup, 
            customertype.customertypedescription as typedescription, 
            customercard.customeraddress, 
            customercard.customeraddressalt, 
            tax.taxcode as taxcode,
            customercard.website, 
            customergrouplist.description as groupdescription, 
            customercard.phone1, 
            customercard.phone2, 
            customercard.fax, customercard.email');
            $this->db->limit($limit);
            $this->db->order_by('customercode_id');
            $this->db->join('customergrouplist','customercard.customergroup=customergrouplist.customergroup');
            $this->db->join('customertype','customercard.customertype=customertype.customertypecode');

            $this->db->join('tax','customercard.tax_id=tax.tax_id');
            $this->db->where('customercode_id', $start);
            $query = $this->db->get('customercard');
            //echo $this->db->last_query();

            //echo $query->num_rows();
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                $row = $query->row();
                $data = $row;
                return $data;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function last_customer(){
            $this->db->select('customercode_id');
            $this->db->limit(1);
            $this->db->order_by('customercode_id','DESC');
            $query = $this->db->get('customercard');
            $row = $query -> row();
            return $row->customercode_id;
        }
```

What seems to be the problem in my codings? Any idea? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the complete error ? And a line number on which you getting the error ?

Comment: Can you point out on which line it cause the error. We can't do blind guesses of which user model you are talking about

Comment: @RahilWazir the lines which cause the error are in the view php starting from $customer_id to $tax_code ;

Comment: @user255798 : can you give printr($data); in the model and see if it prints. because I believe the value returned from model function fetch_customers($limit, $start), returns false because the query returned 0 rows. ie, data is not present in your database.

Comment: @MohammedAshiq actually I have a user 12 in my table. I tried to print but I didn't see any records